# Jquery UI sortable with centered elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have sortable elements in a container that are centered (margin: 0 auto). The problem is that when I start the sort, the selected element jumps to the left as they become position absolutely.

Here's a fiddle that illustrates the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/annam/35MC3/28/

I tried getting the offset position before the sort starts (using a mousedown listener)  and then applying this position to the element when sort starts:

```
function onMouseDown()
{
   startPosition = $(this).offset();
}

function startSort(event,ui)
{
   $(ui.item).css(startPosition);
}
```

Didn't work. I then tried explicitly setting ui.sortable.originalposition to a specific top and left position and this didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Note that I cannot change the structure of the HTML and introduce new containers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/35MC3/113/

```
$('#container').sortable({
    axis: 'y'
});
$('.draggable:not(.ui-sortable-helper)').mouseover(function () {
    var p = $(this).offset();
    $(this).css({
        top: p.top + 'px',
        left: p.left + 'px'
    })
});
```

**Explanation**: `ui-sortable-helper` is the class assigned to the sortable item. So here we just set the initial `top,left` values for the item only when it's hovered but not sorted. The reason why it didn't worked for you is because the `ui.offset` was `undefined` in `start` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`helper`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper) option to return a custom element positioned using [`position()`](http://jqueryui.com/position/) jQuery UI utility method as follows:

```js
$('#container').sortable({
  helper: function(event, elm) {
    return $(elm).clone().position({
      my: "left",
      at: "left",
      of: elm
    });
  },
  axis: 'y'
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0; /*for stack snippet demo*/
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px auto;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="draggable"></div>
  <div class="draggable"></div>
</div>
```